# AngularJS: Loading the module on specific DOM event

Tags: angularjs

I've been banging my head for two days now.
I want to load my module on specific (custom) event.

This is how my page is being loaded:
 1. PageLoad (tabs are loaded)
 2. TabContentLoad (tab's content being loaded via ajax call)

I get this:
`<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="init()"`>
only after TabContentLoad event fires, and that is when I want to load the module.

Any suggestions? Or tips to improve this architecture?
Should I wrap the tabs with `ng-app` and only include the `ng-controller` inside the tab content?

Comment: use angular-lazyload https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Comment: Read about manual initialization https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap but I'm pretty sure that with more context in your question it _might_ be unnecessary (I mean, what's `TabContentLoad` event?)

Comment: @AlonEitan yes it's the custom event I want to trigger the module loading

Comment: @HikeNalbandyan NP, so follow the instructions in the link and it should provide the solution you need

Comment: @AlonEitan This is brilliant!!! Thank you. TODA!

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @AlonEitan:

Read about manual initialization [docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)